# Calling a function from Module1 when a value in the worksheet changes

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have the following function running for use as status indicators on my Excel Sheet

```
Function MapCheck() As String
Dim C(5), OV, i, x, R1
Dim element As Variant, element2 As Variant

R1 = Application.Caller.Row

C(1) = ColorCode(Trim(Range("E" & R1))) 'Generate a priority code for the DDR deliverable
C(2) = ColorCode(Trim(Range("I" & R1))) 'Generate a priority code for the FAT deliverable
C(3) = ColorCode(Trim(Range("L" & R1))) 'Generate a priority code for the SAT deliverable
C(4) = ColorCode(Trim(Range("O" & R1))) 'Generate a priority code for the CUP deliverable
C(5) = ColorCode(Trim(Range("R" & R1))) 'Generate a priority code for the DWG deliverable
OV = 1 'Define the default colour (Best Case)

For i = 1 To 5 'For each of the five columns
    For x = 1 To 5 'Check each of the 5 columns and...
        If C(i) < C(x) Then 'if the latest column has a worst progress than the worst so far
            OV = C(x) 'Change the overal staus to the worst value
        End If
    Next x
Next i

Select Case OV
    Case Is = 3 'If the overall status is 3
        OV = "Red" 'The overall map colour will be Red
    Case Is = 2 'If the overall status is 2
        OV = "Orange" 'The overall map colour will be Orange/Amber
    Case Is = 1 'If the overall status is 1
        OV = "Green" 'The overall map colour will be Green
End Select

MapCheck = OV 'Return the overal map colour for the row/site
```

I then call the function in the workbook like this =@MapCheck()
My problem is when anyone updates a value in any of the columns its checking c1-c5 it does not run the mapcheck function to update it

i tried running the following worksheet change event using examples from here and MSonline help

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E1:R100"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Call Module1.MapCheck
End If
End Sub
```

This just returns

> Runtime error 424 object required

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in a module, then you will want to pass it the worksheet you want it to process like this:

```
Function MapCheck(ws as WorkSheet) As String
```

and then use that worksheet object to qualify your `Range` like this:

```
C(1) = ColorCode(Trim(ws.Range("E" & R1))) 'Generate a priority code for the DDR deliverable
```